# How can I get path to file in composer package

Tags: composer-php

I want to include a default file in a composer package. I would like to copy a file that is located in the package over to project via Robo.  I was thinking I can use the Composer object but had no luck because `$composer->getConfig()` is null.

```
<?php

namespace MyLibrary\MyClass;

use Robo\Tasks as Tasks;
use Composer\Composer as Composer;

/**
 * Base class for Xeno robo commands.
 */
class MyClass extends Tasks {

  public function pathLibrary() {
    $composer = new Composer();
    echo $composer->getConfig()->get('mylibrary');
  }

  public function setup() {
   // Copy file over.
   $this->_exec('cp ' . $this->pathLibrary() . '/src/Starter/myfile.yml ./');
  }

}
```

Anyone know of a way?

Comment: What do you mean by the "composer library path"? Do you probably want to write a [Composer post-install script](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md)?

Comment: Say I have a composer package that contains file in this path: src/Starter/myfile.yml. I want to copy that file to my project. In order to copy it I would need the full path. I'm trying to figure out how I can copy it via my Robo class. I don't want to do it with Composer post-install script.  I just updated sample code with setup function that shows how I want to copy it over.

Comment: Have a look at `__DIR__`, it contains the current directory where your task is placed. Can you build the file path to copy from there?

Comment: @NicoHaase Dah Why didn't I think of that. I think that should work. Can you post as answer so I give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy a file from a directory, but do not know the absolute path of the file (eg. because this is installed as a library to some vendor file), you can have a look at the magic variable `__DIR__`. It contains the path to the current script, so if your script is placed at `/what/ever/directory/script.php`, this resolves to `/what/ever/directory`.

So, if you know the **relative** path between your script and the file to be copied, you can make use of it: in your case, the file to be copied might reside at the relative path `src/Starter/myfile.yml` and the file to run the operation at `src/MyLibrary/MyClass.php` (according to the namespace of the class). To copy it somewhere, you can use the path `$path = __DIR__ . '/../../Starter/myfile.yml`.